# After Grails 4 upgrade my URL Mappings and interceptors no longer work

Tags: grails

I am trying to upgrade from 3.3.x to 4.0.13 but after doing so my URL mappings and interceptors no longer work.  I believe there is a root issue that is the same between the 2 because of debug statements I have in my interceptor make it appear someone in the underlying grails mappings is broken.

URLMappings

```
static mappings = {
        "/api/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            namespace = "admin"
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(redirect: "/app/")
        "/app"(uri: "/index.html")
        "/app/**"(uri: "/index.html")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(redirect: "/app/")
    }
```

UserController

```
class UserController extends AdminController {
    static namespace = "admin";

    def save(UserCommand cmd) {
       [...]
    }
}
```

LoginInterceptor

```
class LoginInterceptor {

    LoginInterceptor() {
        matchAll()
                .excludes(controller: ~/(login|logout|publicLookupSvc)/);
    }

    boolean before() {
        println(controllerNamespace);
        println(controllerName);
        println(actionName);
        println(request.requestURI);

        true
    }
}
```

So the underlying issue I am referring to is that my debug statments in 4.0.13 print `null` whereas in 3.3.x they actually print values

So if I visit the URL: http://localhost:8081/raa/api/admin/user/save

In 3.3

```
println(controllerNamespace); -> admin
println(controllerName); -> user
println(actionName); -> save
println(request.requestURI); -> /raa/api/admin/user/save
```

In 4.0.13

```
println(controllerNamespace); -> null
println(controllerName); -> null
println(actionName); -> null
println(request.requestURI); -> /raa/api/admin/user/save
```

Along with the error stacktrace

```
2022-04-20 13:15:33.303 ERROR --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /raa/api/admin/user/save
URL mapping must either provide redirect information, a controller or a view name to map to!. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL mapping must either provide redirect information, a controller or a view name to map to!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingInfo.<init>(DefaultUrlMappingInfo.java:105)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingInfo.<init>(DefaultUrlMappingInfo.java:99)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.ResponseCodeUrlMapping.match(ResponseCodeUrlMapping.java:136)
    [...]
```

Consequently, since all the attributes are null regarding where my request is suposed to be routed, the `matchAll()` does not work either.  When I vist my `login/logout/publicLookupSvc` controllers the interceptor still gets hit even though it should be skipped.

I feel like once I figure out why those mapping paramters are not being populated correctly everything will fall into place.  I just can't figure out why thats happening.

Grails 4.0.13

JDK 11.0.13

Gradle 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you delcared your `contextPath` in Grails 4.x has changed and this was causing all my URL to be incorrect.  After fixing this everything worked as expected.

Grails 3.x

```
server:
  contextPath: '/myapp'
```

Grails 4.x+

```
server:
  servlet:
     contextPath: '/myapp'
```